# Image segmentation with using a loop

Tags: python

I need to do image segmentation using loops. That is, select a coin. But I have no idea how to do this. Here are my pathetic attempts:

```
import cv2

a=[]

image = cv2.imread(r'E:\coin.jpg')

for line in image:

   for elem in line:
       if elem >=60:
          a.append('1')
       else:
          a.append('0')
cv2.imshow('Gray image', a) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

As a result, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\den22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\123.py", line 9, in <module>
    if elem >=60:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your image is likely a 3D array, not a 2D one. Try checking `image.shape` and you'll probably find it's `x, y, 3` so `elem` isn't a single pixel, but a sequence of pixel values

Comment: One option would be to pass the `cv2.IMREAD.GRAYSCALE` second argument which should give you a 2D array (see the docs: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid iterating over arrays if you possibly can.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(r'E:\coin.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
threshold = 60

binary_mask = np.zeros_like(image)
above_threshold = np.where(image >= 60)
binary_mask[above_threshold] = 1
cv2.imshow(binary_mask)
```

This shows the logic explicitly, creating an array of zeros and then identifying the values of interest and setting those values in the binary_mask to 1. You can also just plot a boolean array:

```
bool_array = image >= 60
cv2.imshow(bool_array)
```